# Pie charts node cytoscape

Tags: cluster-computing, nodes, pie-chart, cytoscape

I have a .txt table like this:

```
column1: Source Node
column2: Target Node
column3: Edge attribute
column4: Source Node attribute
```

the 4th column is a list of floating point numbers like this:

```
example: 0.01,0.8,0.1,0.9
```

these values are percentage values (the sum of all the values in one row is =1), since all the nodes are derived from different conditions.

What I would like to have is a cluster in which each single node is a pie chart, and the arc lenght of each slice is the percentage values. So in the example before I would have a pie chart with arc lenght 1%, 80%, 10%, 9%

How can I do it? If I try to set it in the Image/Chart properties in the Style menu I get some weird error and the nodes disappear from the cluster. Is there a tutorial? Something I can use? I am using Cytoscape 3.3 
Thanks for your help!

Mike

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called EnhancedGraphics for showing graphs in nodes. Cytoscape apps are distributed thru its App Store. This one adds features like gradients and charts. You can go to apps.cytoscape.org and search for extensions.

http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/enhancedgraphics

Adding a chart to a node is simple:

Create a new text column in the node table Add the chart instructions (see below for samples) Set up a visual style that uses the column you created as a passthrough mapping for one of the CustomGraphics styles.

Some example chart instructions:

gradients, basic charts, circos charts, and labels

Note that values can either be provided through a valuelist or through an attributelist. Colors can be by keyword or by providing a color for values above zero, at zero, or below zero. More documentation is being prepared and the development of a user interface to create these columns is underway.

Comment: Thanks, I have implement the apps through properties paint -> custome paint 1 -> Image/chart 1.